# How can you convert a gamma distribution into normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation, gamma-distribution

A region has 200 stores served by a single distribution center. Demand of X during lead time (the time interval between order placement of X and arrival of X) at each store is forecasted to be gamma distributed with mean 22.51 and std dev 16. The company wants a fill-rate of at least 85%.
1)Under this circumstance, how many X does each store need to order?
2)How many X left at end of period? (demand is independent across stores, total demand is 4,502 with std dev 226.3. Normal distribution will work for demand forecast)
3)How many X should be ordered for distribution center to have 85% fill rate?
4)The quantity that company ordered in part (1) is kept entirely at distribution center and delivered to each store only as needed. What would be distribution center's fill rate?

SOLVED. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: But why not look up the expected value for the gamma distribution directly?  Is this some kind of homework problem?

Comment: Please explain what a "gamma-distributed chart" is.

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to solve the problem you have. Perhaps you should ask about the underlying problem instead of asking about the idea you had to solve it.

Comment: What is "an expected value at a certain point" ?

Comment: OK I can't resist anymore - the expected value of a Gamma distribution with shape $a$ and scale $b$ is $ab$.  Does that help, or have I totally misinterpreted the question?  (In any case I second the requests above to clarify what you're asking!)

Comment: What is meant by "an expected value at a _certain point_" (emphasis added)? An expected value is a "global" parameter and has the same value at all points.

Comment: I have F(Q) as cumulative distribution function and L(Q) as loss function, defined as a function that returns expected number of units by which a random variable exceeds the inputted value. My data is gamma distributed with mean 22.51 and standard deviation 16. The problem asks that, There are 200 stores served by a single distribution center. We need to find out how much each store orders their product from the single distribution center, if they want a fill rate of at least 85%. (Fill rate: the minimum amount that the stores need to have in order to satisfy customer demand)

Answer (score 13):

Hope this answer does not seem facetious:

You can transform random variables from one to another with the inverse CDF method:

If $\gamma$ is Gamma distributed (with some fixed parameters), and $F$ its CDF then $F(\gamma)$ has uniform(0,1) distribution.  Thus $\Phi^{-1}(F(\gamma))$ has Normal distribution.

This requires some computation of course, probably more than computing the mean of the Gamma directly.

But I guess any suitable transform would, because the gamma and normal distribution PDF shapes are rather different in general (when the Gamma shape parameter is small).  However, the Gamma distribution is divisible in the shape parameter, i.e. Gamma(shape $=a+b$, scale $=c$) has the same distribution as Gamma$(a,c)$ $+$  Gamma$(b,c)$.  Thus, as Stephane Laurent mentioned, the central limit theorem says that the normal distribution gives a good approximation when the shape parameter is large.

Comment: Different shapes in general, but for a large shape parameter the Gamma distribution can be well approximated by a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: More generally, the cube root of a gamma is closer to a normal than the original. For a more precise but more complicated story search "Wilson-Hilferty transformation".

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent - thanks, good point, edited to reflect this.

Comment: @NickCox - thanks for this too, I've never heard of it!

Comment: There is another normal approximation than can be derived from the normal approximation to the $\chi^2$ distributions than can be found in some $\chi^2$ tables : $$\sqrt{2\chi^2_\nu} \approx {\cal N}(\sqrt{2\nu-1},1)$$ when $\nu$ is large. This is not the approximation obtained from the CLT.
cc @NickCox FYI